# Setting scroll in a div so that a buttons are added dynamically on horizontal overflow

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `table`, inside a `div` with a fixed width.

The table is added dynamically via JavaScript and each row is added based on user input.

The table width and cell widths are all set and fine, and adding information works, but when I get too many rows, the table just continues building...

How to I make the `div` area scrollable so that as the `table` grows and the user can scroll in that `div` area to see the other fields in the table?

In other words, how do I put some buttons to scroll the table left and right on overflow of `div` width.

I want something similar to what is in Notepad++ and Firefox where you get left and right buttons to scroll through the opened tabs.

Please help me out to do this...

Comment: Please include the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript that you are using now. (A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be helpful as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Just created a [**`page`**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q96YA/1/) with up and down button without showing any scroll.
Watch that [**`Fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q96YA/1/) and let me know if it is helpful.

Comment: i dont want to get scroll under the div.... as it will change the whole page ..... so trying to add some buttons to scroll which will help me out

Comment: watch the fiddle @user3492935

Comment: I am really grateful for this tip :)

Comment: @Sujit Please add the applicable code from the JSFiddle to your post.